# Implicit default values for parameters?

Tags: c++, parameters, default-value

If I got this function, fun(t1, t2, t3), and I call it by fun(v1, v2), is it possible to get a default value for v3 though it hasn't been specified what that would be? Such as bool being false, pointer being null, int being 0 etc. Or should that raise compiler error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will raise a compiler error if the function isn't overloaded.

If you can't change the prototype, you can overload it yourself:

```
void fun (bool t1, bool t2)
{ 
   fun (t1,t2, true); //or whatever
}
```

or if you can change it, you can declare a default for the parameter like this:

```
void fun (bool t1, bool t2, bool t3 = true)
{ 
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks, that's what I was afraid of.. This occurrence of "implicit default parameter value" that I found had me quite tripped up. Turned out the piece wasn't even getting compiled. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Declare it like this:

```
void fun (Foo t1, Bar t2, bool t3 = false)
{...}
```

When you put an = and a value, that parameter gains a default value if none is provided. However, you must start using them from the right side of the parameter list.